# Как задать строгое соответствие в регулярном выражении?

Tags: jquery, регулярные-выражения

Есть много доменов для почты, gmail, mail, yandex и тд

Я проверяю конкретно mail на соответствие того, что ввели в input email. И мне нужно **не** пропускать именно **mail**

Отрезаю не нужные части value - всё что находится до знака @ и потом всё, что находится после точки:

По итогу вводим **test@mail.ru** > на выходе останется только **mail**

```
let mailDomenValue = $(form).find('input[name="email"]').val().split('@')[1].split('.')[0];

mailDomenValue.match(/mail/)
```

Теперь столкнулся с проблемой - как пропустить **gmail**, но не пропустить просто **mail**

.match(/mail/) ищет сочетание **mail** даже в середине слова.

Comment: Границы слова - `/\bmail\b/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/^mail$/` — Спец-символы означают: `^` начало строки, `$` конец строки.

```js
console.log( /^mail$/.test('mail') ); // true
console.log( /^mail$/.test('gmail') ); // false
```

Comment: Спасибо! А другой комментарий - Границы слова - /\bmail\b/ 
Это тоже хорошее решение?

Comment: @Spawnet `\b` применимо в этом случае, но это ссылка на "границу слова". Т.е. если есть несколько символов подряд из `[A-Za-z0-9_]`, левая и правая части такого "слова" считаются `\b` (состоящие из другого символа не из вышеуказанного списка, или начало/конец строки) → https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html А `^...$` - это прямо начало и конец строки, независимо от содержимого того, что "между"